# Anyone know what might be causing this maps problem?

Tags: php, javascript, css, google-maps

http://robbieduggan.com/bridgedale-homes/ppc1/

In the above, click the Maps heading in the Accordion. Does anyone know what might be causing the odd problem where only the top right of the maps shows? It fixes itself when you load up Firebug or Chromes Inspect Element feature.

All suggestions welcome :)

Comment: thats because I'm working on a suggestion below. Hang on and ill make a perma link

Comment: http://robbieduggan.com/bridgedale-homes/ppc1/index.php done. The link above is the problem as it stands again :)

Comment: Seems to me like the map doesn't think it's 530x530 pixels.  It just redraws itself when you force it to (with the chrome debugger for example).  I'm not familiar with this, but probably try and play with the size of the map that's drawn. (the other hint to this is that the pin is off center)

Comment: because of the pin being off center, it feels like a weird css position problem. As thought its absolute positioned to the top right of the table or something. And thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading your map on click

```
$("#mapAccordionTrigger").click(function() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var lat = 53.559991;
            var lng = -6.799526;

            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
            map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lng), 15);

            var infoTabs = [
                new GInfoWindowTab("Address", "4 Bed Detached Houses<br />From &euro;249,000"),
                ];

            // Place a marker in the center of the map and open the info window
            var marker = new GMarker(map.getCenter());
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                marker.openInfoWindowTabsHtml(infoTabs);
            });
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            marker.openInfoWindowTabsHtml(infoTabs);

            var point = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
            panoramaOptions = {
                latlng: point
            };
            pano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetview"), panoramaOptions);
            GEvent.addListener(pano);

        }
});
```

Comment: http://robbieduggan.com/bridgedale-homes/ppc1/index2.php

I made that change and they dont load. Do I need to add anything to the div I actually click on?

Comment: Yes, sorry, `mapAccordionTrigger` was just some made up id.  You need to assign it to the `a` tag of the map accordion.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. Still no luck with the load though: http://robbieduggan.com/bridgedale-homes/ppc1/index2.php :(

Comment: I edited my code above, also remove `onload="load()"` from your body tag.

Comment: Both done, but still no luck. http://robbieduggan.com/bridgedale-homes/ppc1/index2.php

Comment: Odd, I would throw an alert in there to make sure the click is working.

Comment: No, its not triggering, how odd

Comment: Your answer wasnt exactly it, but it pointed me in the right direction. So you get the tick :)